# I can't execute command inside vim but it can be executed in shell?

Tags: python, vim, pip

I use vim, mac os x, virtualenv and zsh to develop python.

But i found a quite strange thing that, After i using virtualenv to create a environment and  install a python package with `pip install fabric` and execute `fab` in command line. It works well.
Then i open vim and execute `fab` with `:!fab`, it give me following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                  │ * Restarting with reloader
  File "/usr/local/bin/fab", line 5, in <module>                                    │ * Detected change in '/Users/ccheng/workspace/rms-rest/rms/account.py', reloading
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point                                      │ * Restarting with reloader
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2793, in <module> │ * Detected change in '/Users/ccheng/workspace/rms-rest/rms/account.py', reloading
                                                                                    │ * Restarting with reloader
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 673, in require   │ * Detected change in '/Users/ccheng/workspace/rms-rest/rms/rms.py', reloading
    def subscribe(self, callback):                                                  │ * Restarting with reloader
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 576, in resolve   │ * Detected change in '/Users/ccheng/workspace/rms-rest/rms/rms.py', reloading
    plugin_env, full_env=None, installer=None, fallback=True                        │ * Restarting with reloader
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: Fabric==1.8.0                                   │ * Detected change in 'run.py', reloading
                                                                                    │ * Restarting with reloader
shell returned 1
```

I think it was caused by when i open vim, some `python path` variable has been reset, so i can't find the packages installed in virtualenv.

Comment: Did you `source bin/activate` again in your vim shell?

Comment: what are the respective results of `echo $PATH`, and `:!echo $PATH`? It sounds like you've answered your own question though. Path issue

Comment: @moofins It seems that it doesn't need to source again in vim shell.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the issue through set a default shell in terminal configuration. I don't know what is different between this and setting default shell using 'chsh', but it works. Thanks everyone.